# validación de si contiene algo o está vacío

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

necesito que me desactive un boton o me lo active según si dentro de un div contiene html o no es decir por ejemplo:si el div está vacio que active el boton:

```
<diV id="añadir_columna1">

</diV>
```

o si contiene algo que desactive el boton:

```
 <diV id="añadir_columna1">

  <div class="panel-body">

      <p>Propiedad: texto</p>

         <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control p" id="p" placeholder="texto">

         </div>


        </div>

</div>
```

yo lo tengo es esto pero solo me reconoce el segundo console.log(); es decir solo me lo desactiva y quiero que me haga las dos cosas segun si esta vacio o lleno el div

```
    document.getElementById("div_1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

var data = $('#añadir_columna1').html()

if (data == "") {// ver esto cuando venga


    console.log($('#añadir_columna1').html)
     $('#grupo_propiedades').removeAttr('disabled');// activar el boton

    return false;

} else {

    console.log($('#añadir_columna1').html)

     $('#grupo_propiedades').attr("disabled", true);//desactivar  el boton

}
```

Comment: has intentado con null o undefined en ves de ""? que te manda el console.log()?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
if($("#añadir_columna1").children().length>0){
   $("button").prop("disabled",false);
}else{
   $("button").prop("disabled",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando agregues el `div` vacío hazlo de esta manera:

```
<div id="añadir_columna1"></div>
```

No así:

```
<div id="añadir_columna1">

</div>
```

Así te indicará correctamente cuando no tiene datos.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que si adentro del `div` hay espacios o saltos de línea algunos navegadores lo interpretan como contenido, por lo que se sigue considerando como que `html()` contiene elementos. Para eso yo uso esta función que ayuda a quitar todos esos espacios y saltos de líneas y ahora si comparar si tiene contenido o no.

```js
document.getElementById("div_1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

  var data = $('#añadir_columna1')

  if (isEmpty(data)) {// ver esto cuando veng

      console.log("Vacío");
       $('#grupo_propiedades').removeAttr('disabled');// activar el boton

      return false;

  } else {

      console.log("Datos:"+ data.html())

       $('#grupo_propiedades').attr("disabled", true);//desactivar  el boton

 }
  });
  
  function isEmpty( el ){
      return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div_1'>Haz clic
  <div id="añadir_columna1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias a todos me habéis ayudado